# How to use if else in flutter for icons?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to change icons based on information fetched from the database. How can I do that?

```
if(documentSnapshot['visiting period']=="Sold"){
                            Icon(MyIcons.aquas),

                          },
else{
...
}
```

Can anyone help with this as I get the error

```
The element type 'List<Icon>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ternary operator inside the icon widget like this

```
Icon(true ? Icons.abc : Icons.abc_rounded)
```

replace true with your condition.
the value after ? will be called if the condition is true and the value after : will be called when condition is false

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
Icon(documentSnapshot['visiting period']=="Sold"? Icons.one : Icons.two)),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that returns an icon.

```
body: Container(
    _getApplicableIcon(documentSnapshot['visiting period']);
  ),

_getApplicableIcon(String visitingPeriod) {
    switch (visitingPeriod) {
    case "Sold":
       return Icon(MyIcons.aquas);
    case "Not Sold":
       return Icon(MyIcons.elseIcon);
    default:
       return Icon(MyIcons.defaultIcon);
    }
}
```

If you dont want an icon as default you can return container();

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using two way.

```
documentSnapshot['visiting period']=="Sold" ?  Icon(MyIcons.aquas) : Icon(MyIcons.(your icon name);
```

Or

```
Icon(documentSnapshot['visiting period']=="Sold" ? MyIcons.aquas : Icon(MyIcons.(your icon name));
```